# AWS CloudFront not able to point to specific url subpage

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using reactJS to develop our website, which I uploaded to S3 bucket with both index and error documents pointing to "index.html".

If I use the s3 bucket's url, say http://assets.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com", I get served my index.html. So far, so good. If I then go to specific subpage by deliberately appending /merchant, it goes there to without any problem although there is no folder called /merchant in my s3 bucket.

However, if I now attach this S3 bucket to my CloudFront distribution, and I try to directly address "https://blah.cloudfront.net/merchant", it responds with "access denied" because it could not find the subfolder /merchant in s3 bucket.

How do people get around this issue with CloudFront? I have so many virtual subpages that don't map to physical folders.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer.

In the cloudfront, set a custom error response like this[image: AWS CloudFront custom error response for 403]

Comment: Thanks a lot form this solution.